# Parsing formatted strings in Go

Tags: string, go

**The Problem**

I have slice of `string` values wherein each value is formatted based on a template. In my particular case, I am trying to parse Markdown URLs as shown below:

```
- [What did I just commit?](#what-did-i-just-commit)
- [I wrote the wrong thing in a commit message](#i-wrote-the-wrong-thing-in-a-commit-message)
- [I committed with the wrong name and email configured](#i-committed-with-the-wrong-name-and-email-configured)
- [I want to remove a file from the previous commit](#i-want-to-remove-a-file-from-the-previous-commit)
- [I want to delete or remove my last commit](#i-want-to-delete-or-remove-my-last-commit)
- [Delete/remove arbitrary commit](#deleteremove-arbitrary-commit)
- [I tried to push my amended commit to a remote, but I got an error message](#i-tried-to-push-my-amended-commit-to-a-remote-but-i-got-an-error-message)
- [I accidentally did a hard reset, and I want my changes back](#i-accidentally-did-a-hard-reset-and-i-want-my-changes-back)
```

**What I want to do?**

I am looking for ways to parse this into a value of type:

```
type Entity struct {
    Statement string
    URL string
}
```

**What have I tried?**

As you can see, all the items follow the pattern: `- [{{ .Statement }}]({{ .URL }})`. I tried using the `fmt.Sscanf` function to scan each string as:

```
var statement, url string
fmt.Sscanf(s, "[%s](%s)", &statement, &url)
```

This results in:

```
statement = "I"
url = ""
```

The issue is with the scanner storing space-separated values only. I do not understand why the URL field is not getting populated based on this rule.

How can I get the Markdown values as mentioned above?

**EDIT**: As suggested by Marc, I will add couple of clarification points:

1. This is a general purpose question on parsing strings based on a format. In my particular case, a Markdown parser might help me but my intention to learn how to handle such cases in general where a library might not exist.
2. I have read the official documentation before posting here.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use an existing markdown parser? eg: https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/russross/blackfriday.v2

Comment: This is a general purpose question on parsing strings given a format.
I think a markdown parser will be an overkill for my task. 
Moreover, there is no guarantee that a suitable parser will always exist.

Comment: Ok, then please read the [fmt scanning docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#hdr-Scanning), it clearly states: " the %s verb (...) stops consuming input at the first space or newline character". It then can't find a `]` so never gets to parsing the URL. You shouldn't ignore the returns from `Sscanf`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I did read the doc before asking here and I have also mentioned in this my post.

Comment: "there is no guarantee that a suitable parser will always exist" - do you just want to accomplish this by using regexp?

Comment: Thank you and sorry for asking such an easy question.

Comment: There are no silver bullet to string manipulation and parsing. You always need to pick a specified tool. In the op's case, using regex is most reasonable (a MD parser is too heavy for the simple case). If you want some exercise, write codes to pair matching bracelets can do the job too.

Comment: @KshitijSaraogi there is no general solution to such a general problem, only a multitude of different approaches, which is why the guidance to ask about "a specific programming problem" exists :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note:** The following solution only works for "simple", non-escaped input markdown links. If this suits your needs, go ahead and use it. For full markdown-compatibility you should use a proper markdown parser such as [gopkg.in/russross/blackfriday.v2](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/russross/blackfriday.v2).

---

You could use regexp to get the link text and the URL out of a markdown link.

So the general input text is in the form of:

```
[some text](somelink)
```

A regular expression that models this:

```
\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)
```

Where:

- `\[` is the literal `[`
- `([^\]]+)` is for the `"some text"`, it's everything except the closing square brackets
- `\]` is the literal `]`
- `\(` is the literal `(`
- `([^)]+)` is for the `"somelink"`, it's everything except the closing brackets
- `\)` is the literal `)`

Example:

```
r := regexp.MustCompile(`\[([^\]]+)\]\(([^)]+)\)`)

inputs := []string{
    "[Some text](#some/link)",
    "[What did I just commit?](#what-did-i-just-commit)",
    "invalid",
}

for _, input := range inputs {
    fmt.Println("Parsing:", input)
    allSubmatches := r.FindAllStringSubmatch(input, -1)

    if len(allSubmatches) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("   No match!")
    } else {
        parts := allSubmatches[0]
        fmt.Println("   Text:", parts[1])
        fmt.Println("   URL: ", parts[2])
    }
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UkqemSNO0QO)):

```
Parsing: [Some text](#some/link)
   Text: Some text
   URL:  #some/link
Parsing: [What did I just commit?](#what-did-i-just-commit)
   Text: What did I just commit?
   URL:  #what-did-i-just-commit
Parsing: invalid
   No match!
```

Comment: That would work for the examples listed by OP. But do note that `[\[foo\]](foo.com)` is valid markdown.

Comment: @Marc You're right, I forgot about that. I added a note mentioning this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a simple lexer in pure-Go code for this use case. There's a [great talk](https://youtu.be/HxaD_trXwRE) by Rob Pike from years ago that goes into the design of [text/template](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) which would be applicable. The implementation chains together a series of state functions into an overall state machine, and delivers the tokens out through a channel (via Goroutine) for later processing.